# Compact letter displays with non-estimable cases

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons

Compact letter displays are similar to grouping bars often used to display the results of a multiple-comparison procedure, but can be used more generally. You give a list of sample means (or other statistics) and associate one or more letters with each mean. Two means sharing the same letter are not significantly different according to the procedure used. Two means having no letters in common are significantly different.

My question is: **What should one do if some of the means are not estimable?** (perhaps because of missing cells in the design)

From one point of view, the non-estimable case(s) should get every letter used, because obviously you haven't found it to be statistically different than the others. So the display could look like this:

```
 treat    lsmean      SE df  lower.CL upper.CL .group
 A      6.666667 3.25747 18 -0.177024 13.51036  1    
 B      8.500000 3.25747 18  1.656309 15.34369  1    
 C     14.333333 3.25747 18  7.489643 21.17702  12   
 D            NA      NA NA        NA       NA  12   
 E     25.500000 3.25747 18 18.656309 32.34369   2
```

The other point of view would be that this unnecessarily clutters the display. So you should show this:

```
 treat    lsmean      SE df  lower.CL upper.CL .group
 A      6.666667 3.25747 18 -0.177024 13.51036  1    
 B      8.500000 3.25747 18  1.656309 15.34369  1    
 C     14.333333 3.25747 18  7.489643 21.17702  12   
 D            NA      NA NA        NA       NA
 E     25.500000 3.25747 18 18.656309 32.34369   2
```

So what do you all think? Assign letters to the `NA` results, or not?

### footnote

There are also cases where the differences are estimable, but the means themselves are not. So it is possible to get a display like this:

```
 treat lsmean SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 A         NA NA NA       NA       NA  1   
 B         NA NA NA       NA       NA  1   
 C         NA NA NA       NA       NA  12   
 D         NA NA NA       NA       NA  12   
 E         NA NA NA       NA       NA   2
```

Note that if scheme 1 was used in the above example, we cannot tell whether the differences involving `C` or `D` are estimable or not. Of course, in such a situation, we really would be well advised to display the actual estimates of the differences instead!

Answer (score 2):

Given just the primary information in your question, I'd be moderately inclined to choose your option #2 (i.e. leaving blank). This because the blank (or NA, if you prefer) conveys different information than the use of all possible letters/group indicators - it clearly shows that the relevant information is *missing*, not that you have high uncertainty in the estimate.

But with the added information in the footnote, the case for leaving blank seems overwhelming. There's no way at present to distinguish between what is going on with Group D in Table 1 and Table 3; Table 2 makes the difference clear.

I would generally prefer a graphical presentation of this sort of result, however.